# Can drupal be installed on a subdomain and used on the main domain?

Tags: database, subsites

I was thinking about installing Drupal on admin.myexample.com for clients to access an add and edit news posts & products.

Then just using myexample.com as the main site. Calling the database and entries to their pages with PHP/SQL.

Is this practical?

I've been trying to learn my way around Drupal, I know this wouldn't be a way to learn. I'm much more comfortable writing the pages up myself than manipulating Drupal pages (at this point in time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have Drupal run in subdomain and have a completely different web site coded on the domain root.

Just make sure that the subdomain is directed at the Drupal root. To be clear, the Drupal root directory is the one that contains the following files:

authorize.php
CHANGELOG.txt
COPYRIGHT.txt
cron.php
.gitignore
.htaccess
includes
index.php
INSTALL.mysql.txt
INSTALL.pgsql.txt
install.php
INSTALL.sqlite.txt
INSTALL.txt
LICENSE.txt
MAINTAINERS.txt
misc
modules
profiles
README.txt
robots.txt
scripts
sites
themes
update.php
UPGRADE.txt
web.config
xmlrpc.php

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it. I think it will be much easier for me to do this in the meanwhile while I learn the ropes in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

With Drupal (and many other CMSs) you don't need to have a separate domain for the admin area. Users simply login at domain.com/user/login.

If you especially want to use admin.domain.com as the login URL for users then a redirect would do fine, it is a kindof cool address.

But if you are thinking of writing your own code to get the content from the Drupal database for your main site then you are (just slightly) under-using Drupal. It is both the Content Management and Content Display platform and you would be creating your own version of the theme layer and hooks etc (might be fun though - definitely faster :).

The only advantages I could see in spreading out the admin (logged in) area of Drupal across to another domain would be in using a website caching service or some custom security for some reason.

So my advice is:

Yes, you can install Drupal on a sub domain, it is a domain in itself.
But no, don't bother having an admin domain and writing your own code to get the content from the database. Use Drupal for what its good at.